# Which of <random>'s random number engines should one actually use in practice? std::mt19937?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Suppose you want to use C++ `<random>` facilities in a practical program (for some definition of "practical" — the constraints here are kind of part of this question). You've got code roughly like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int seed = get_user_provided_seed_value(argc, argv);
    if (seed == 0) seed = std::random_device()();
    ENGINE g(seed);  // TODO: proper seeding?
    go_on_and_use(g);
}
```

My question is, *what type should you use for `ENGINE`?*

- I used to always say `std::mt19937` because it was quick to type and had name recognition. But these days it seems like [everyone's saying](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.06437.pdf) that the Mersenne Twister is very heavyweight and cache-unfriendly and doesn't even pass all the statistical tests that others do.
- I'd like to say `std::default_random_engine` because it's the obvious "default." But I don't know if it varies from platform to platform, *and* I don't know if it's statistically any good.
- Since everyone's on a 64-bit platform these days, should we at least be using `std::mt19937_64` over `std::mt19937`?
- I'd like to say `pcg64` or `xoroshiro128` because they seem well-respected and lightweight, but they don't exist in `<random>` at all.
- I don't know anything about `minstd_rand`, `minstd_rand0`, `ranlux24`, `knuth_b`, etc. — surely they must be good for something?

Obviously there are some competing constraints here.

- Strength of the engine. (`<random>` has no cryptographically strong PRNGs, but still, some of the standardized ones are "weaker" than others, right?)
- `sizeof` the engine.
- Speed of its `operator()`.
- Ease of seeding. `mt19937` is notoriously hard to seed properly because it has so much state to initialize.
- Portability between library vendors. If one vendor's `foo_engine` produces different numbers from another vendor's `foo_engine`, that's not good for some applications. (Hopefully this rules out nothing except maybe `default_random_engine`.)

Weighing all these constraints as best you can, what would you say is the ultimate "best-practice staying-within-the-standard-library" answer? Should I just keep using `std::mt19937`, or what?

Comment: To your last point, all the standard engine adapters are specified to return a particular value on a particular consecutive invocation of the default constructed one, so they should be portable.

Answer (score 19):

[C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) lists all the random engines currently provided by C++. However, the selection of engines leaves a lot to be desired (e.g., see my list of [high-quality random generators](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#High_Quality_RNGs_Requirements)). For instance:

- `default_random_engine` is implementation-defined, so it's unknown whether the engine has statistical flaws that the application may care about.
- `linear_congruential_engine` implements linear congruential generators. However, they tend to have poor quality unless the modulus is prime and very big (at least 64 bits). Also, they can't admit more seeds than their modulus.
- `minstd_rand0` and `minstd_rand` admit only about 2^31 seeds. `knuth_b` wraps a `minstd_rand0` and does a Bays–Durham shuffle of it.
- `mt19937` and `mt19937_64` could admit a lot more seeds if they were better initialized (e.g., by initializing a `std::seed_seq` with multiple outputs of `random_device`, not just one), but they use about 2500 bytes of state.
- `ranlux24` and `ranlux48` use about 577 bits of state but they are slow (they work by keeping some and discarding other pseudorandom outputs).

However, C++ also has two engines that wrap another engine to potentially improve its randomness properties:

- `discard_block_engine` discards some of the outputs of a given random engine.
- `shuffle_order_engine` implements a Bays–Durham shuffle of a given random engine.

For instance, it's possible, say, to have a Bays–Durham shuffle of `mt19937`, `ranlux24`, or a custom `linear_congruential_engine` with `shuffle_order_engine`. Perhaps the wrapped engine is better quality than the original one. However, it's hard to predict the new engine's statistical quality without [testing it](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/randomtest.md).

Thus, pending such tests, it seems that `mt19937` is the most practical engine in the C++ standard for now. I am aware, however, of at least one proposal to add another random number engine to future versions of C++ (see [C++ paper P2075](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/802)).

Answer (score 1):

According to [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/), `default_random_engine`:

> Is the library implemention's selection of a generator **that provides at least *acceptable* engine behavior for *relatively casual, inexpert, and/or lightweight use.***

So for *lightweight use* you don't need to be worry about anything, seed `default_random_engine` with `Epoch Time (time(0))` and that would be fine enough ;)

Comment: I believe that the issue here is portability. While the default may be an engine that performs well, it may not be reproduceable on another platform.

Comment: @bremen_matt Hmm... Well, why do we need to reproduce a "random" number?

Comment: Testing. For testing purposes, you need reproduceable inputs. At the same time, you may want or need those inputs to be random. For instance, most machine learning algorithms assume that parameters are randomly initialized. Ransac, CNNs, DNNs,... many algorithms require random parameters.